# Vue wait until external request finished

Tags: vue.js, vimeo

I have a page in my Vue application which does an animation on route enter. However because I embedded a Vimeo video in this page, the frames drop from 60 to 20fps during the animation. I think it's because the request to the Vimeo server has to be made and is not finished when the animation starts.

I would like to preload the embedded Vimeo video on the first site load or somehow wait until the request has finished and then start the animation. How do I do that?

The video is embedded like this in the parent component and the animation is in the `projecttop` child component:

```
<div>
  <projecttop></projecttop>
  <div class="vimeo-container">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/397648215" frameborder="0" allow="fullscreen"allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div>
</div>

export default {
  name: 'parentcomponent',
  components: {
    projecttop
  }
}
```

This is the child component with the animation:

```
<script>

import { gsap } from "gsap";

export default {
  name: "projecttop",
  methods: {
    slideIn() {
      var tl = gsap.timeline()
      tl.from('#project-title', {
        delay: 0.5,
        duration: 0.8,
        y: 100,
        opacity: 0,
        ease: "circ.out",
      })
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    if(document.readyState === "complete") {
      this.slideIn()
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the code where your animation is initiated?

Comment: Hi, I added the code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this in your parent component:

```
<projecttop :start-animation="videoLoaded"></projecttop>
<div class="vimeo-container">
  <iframe
    src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/397648215"
    frameborder="0"
    allow="fullscreen"
    allowfullscreen
    @load="videoLoaded = true
  >
  </iframe>
</div>

...
data() {
  return {
    videoLoaded: false,
  }
},
```

Then, in your child component, pass in the value of `videoLoaded` and add a watcher to monitor when this is updated to `true`:

```
props: {
  startAnimation: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  }
},
watch: {
  startAnimation(val) {
    if (val) this.slideIn();
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I will need to change a few things in gsap, but that's fine.